# Как можно узнать загруженность БД по отношению к другим БД на сервере?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Допусти есть сервер, на нем 5 БД.
Как я могу получить с высокой точностью базу с которой происходит большая работа, чем с другими базами?

Comment: Судя по всему, вы так или иначе столкнулись с проблемами производительности. В этом случае стоит не искать наиболее используемую БД (что вам это даст?), а описать ситуацию целиком.

Comment: Мне нужна эта статистика, что бы на основании нее выставить приоритеты в одной другой программке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно получить данные о текущих запросах на сервере с помощью `sys.dm_exec_requests`. Результаты можно сгруппировать по базам и получить картину по количеству запросов выполняющихся на каждой из баз. Можно все оформить в виде хранимки и дергать ее по мере надобности.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно запустить SQL Server Profiler, в нем поставить фильтр на Duration больше 1000 мс. Во вкладке Events Selection установить флажок Show All Columns и в появившихся дополнительных колонках выбрать Database Name для всех типов событий. Нажимаем Run. Спустя некоторое время создастся таблица медленных обращений к базам сервера. Если визуально сразу не бросается в глаза, что обращения к одной из баз преобладают, то можно скопировать таблицу в эксель и отфильтровать по колонке Database Name.

Comment: Как я могу получить данную информаю непосредственно для c#?

Comment: @iluxa1810 , в профайлере, после того, как запишете снимок, нажмите Save As -> Table. Далее, задайте название таблицы, куда будет экспортирован отчет. После экспорта, используя LINQ запросы к базе данных получите нужные вам данные.
Недостаток этого метода в его статичности. Каждый новый отчет придётся делать руками, каждый новый раз.